# Why am I a getting Segmentation Fault when running mongodump

Tags: mongodb

Running Mac OS High Sierra.

Run the following in the terminal

```
1st terminal mongod (it starts)
2nd terminal mongo (it starts)
3rd terminal mongodump -h ds1.mlab.com:276 -d heroku_ppggggg2 -u meuser -p V444N -o /dump
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Not sure what is going on?

UPDATE:

Followed this to a super big **T**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Everything works as stated in the link above until I run `mongo`

Result of running `mongo`:

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2019-04-13T23:20:06.810-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-04-13T23:20:06.810-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-04-13T23:20:06.810-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-04-13T23:20:06.810-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

I installed community v4.0 yet mongo says it is running 3.0?

I run

```
mongodump -h 16-a1.mlab.com:216 -d heroku_ppg2 -u jmen2 -p V3f22TN -o /backup
Segmentation fault: 11

mongodump --version
Segmentation fault: 11

brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

UPDATE 2:

Fixed this by dragging old mongo version to trashbin via Finder and rebooted my machine.

Comment: `mongodump --version`???. Looking at your last post you have a ***very old*** MongoDB installed, and presumably tools. I suggest a `brew update` and again [**Please read the installation instructions in full**.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) as again if you are running `mongod` in a terminal, then it indicates to me that you have not fully read and followed those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by dragging all old version of Mongo to the trashbin via Finder.

Rebooted my system.